# Read Multitag XML file and store in data frame in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Hi I have a big XML file having below format, I want all the tag and his value need to be stored in a data frame like tags are column and values in records  .

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<positioning_record>
    <record>
        <reference_id>20190714121625000001</reference_id>
        <positioning_request_time utc_off="+0530">20190714121625</positioning_request_time>
        <positioning_response_time utc_off="+0530">201990714121625</positioning_response_time>
        <network type="MSG"></network>
        <cell_identity>
            <gsm_cell_identity>
                <mcc>6789</mcc>
                <mnc>5677</mnc>
                <lac>4645645</lac>
                <cid>24564</cid>
            </gsm_cell_identity>
        </cell_identity>
        <client type="Emxxxxr5tiyoerw"></client>
        <requested_QoS>
            <horizontalAccuracy>3456</horizontalAccuracy>
            <responseTime type="delay_tolerant"></responseTime>
        </requested_QoS>
        <MSUE_capability>
            <AGPS_capability type="None"></AGPS_capability>
        </MSUE_capability>
        <response_data type="Success">
            <position_data>
                <PositioningMethodAndUsage method="e-cid" locationReturn="YES">
                    <positionresultCode>1</positionresultCode>
                    <position_estimate>
                        <pointWithUncertaintyEllipse>
                            <geographicalCoordinates>
                                <latitudeSign type="defgrt"></latitudeSign>
                                <latitude>456789</latitude>
                                <longitude>987654</longitude>
                            </geographicalCoordinates>
                            <uncertaintyEllipse>
                                <uncertaintySemiMajor>456</uncertaintySemiMajor>
                                <uncertaintySemiMinor>876</uncertaintySemiMinor>
                                <orientationOfMajorAxis>2345</orientationOfMajorAxis>
                            </uncertaintyEllipse>
                            <confidence>1234</confidence>
                        </pointWithUncertaintyEllipse>
                    </position_estimate>
                    <obtainedAccuracy>
                        <obtainedhorAccuracy>54321</obtainedhorAccuracy>
                    </obtainedAccuracy>
                    <timeStamp utc_off="+0530">20190714121625</timeStamp>
                </PositioningMethodAndUsage>
            </position_data>
        </response_data>
    </record>
    <record>
        <reference_id>20190714121625000002</reference_id>
        <positioning_request_time utc_off="+0530">20190714121625</positioning_request_time>
        <positioning_response_time utc_off="+0530">20190714121625</positioning_response_time>
        <network type="Gde"></network>
        <cell_identity>
            <gsm_cell_identity>
                <mcc>34567</mcc>
                <mnc>8765</mnc>
                <lac>87654</lac>
                <cid>1234</cid>
            </gsm_cell_identity>
        </cell_identity>
        <client type="Emergency"></client>
        <requested_QoS>
            <horizontalAccuracy>2342</horizontalAccuracy>
            <responseTime type="delay_tolerant"></responseTime>
        </requested_QoS>
        <MSUE_capability>
            <AGPS_capability type="Both"></AGPS_capability>
        </MSUE_capability>
        <response_data type="Failure">
            <cause>5</cause>
            <position_data>
            </position_data>
        </response_data>
    </record>
```

I want all the tags between Records to be keep as a record
including (response_data type="Success" ( like success or failure ))

Have tried below code

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
import re
tree = ET.parse('sample.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
data = []

def get_tail(root):
    for child in root:
        #print(child.tag,child.text)
        tag = re.sub(r"[\n\t\s]*", "", str(child.tag))
        value = re.sub(r"[\n\t\s]*", "", str(child.text))
        if not value : 
            value = "NAN"
        #temp = [tag,value]
        #data.append(temp)

        get_tail(child)
        temp = [tag,value]
        data.append(temp)
        #print( data)
        
        
        
        
get_tail(root)

print(data)
cols = ("records","reference_id","positioning_request_time","positioning_response_time","network","cell_identity","gsm_cell_identity","mcc","mnc","lac","cid","client","gsm_cell_identity","horizontalAccuracy","responseTime","MSUE_capability","AGPS_capability","response_data","position_data","PositioningMethodAndUsage","positionresultCode","position_estimate","pointWithUncertaintyEllipse","geographicalCoordinates","latitudeSign","latitude","longitude","uncertaintyEllipse","uncertaintySemiMajor","uncertaintySemiMinor","orientationOfMajorAxis","confidence","obtainedAccuracy","obtainedhorAccuracy","timeStamp")
df = pd.DataFrame(data).T
df.columns = cols 
   
print(df)
```

Its gives me the out out but in a 2 rows a and multiple columns . also tried not to do transpose of DF even not working .

the expected out put will be .
"records","reference_id","positioning_request_time","positioning_response_time","network","cell_identity","gsm_cell_identity","mcc","mnc","lac","cid","client","gsm_cell_identity","horizontalAccuracy","responseTime","MSUE_capability","AGPS_capability","response_data","position_data","PositioningMethodAndUsage","positionresultCode","position_estimate","pointWithUncertaintyEllipse","geographicalCoordinates","latitudeSign","latitude","longitude","uncertaintyEllipse","uncertaintySemiMajor","uncertaintySemiMinor","orientationOfMajorAxis","confidence","obtainedAccuracy","obtainedhorAccuracy","timeStamp"
'NAN', '20210714121625000001', '20210714121625', '20210714121625', 'None', 'NAN', 'NAN', '405', '67', '5035', '21621', 'None', 'NAN', '13', 'None', 'NAN', 'None', 'NAN', 'NAN', 'NAN', '1', 'NAN', 'NAN', 'NAN', 'None', '2245323', '4112646', 'NAN', '35', '26', '90', '80', 'NAN', '162', '20210714121625'
'NAN' '20210714121625000002', '20210714121625', '20210714121625', 'None', 'NAN', 'NAN', '404', '05', '5823', '2373', 'None', 'NAN', '13', 'None', 'NAN', 'None', 'NAN', '5', 'NAN'
'NAN' '20210714121625000003', '20210714121625', '20210714121625', 'None', 'NAN', 'NAN', '404', '15', '10021', '35846', 'None', 'NAN', '13', 'None', 'NAN', 'None', 'NAN', 'NAN', 'NAN', '1', 'NAN', 'NAN', 'NAN', 'None', '2496594', '3774627', '0', '37', '45', '89', '80', 'NAN', '330', '20210714121625'
'NAN', '20210714121626000004', '20210714121626', '20210714121626', 'None', 'NAN', 'NAN', '404', '15', '61995', '43038', 'None', 'NAN', '25', 'None', 'NAN', 'None', 'NAN', 'NAN', 'NAN', '1', 'NAN', 'NAN', 'NAN', 'None', '2445796', '3802090', 'NAN', '43', '35', '75', '80', 'NAN', '365', '20210714121626'
'NAN', '20210714121626000005', '20210714121626', '20210714121626', 'None', 'NAN', 'NAN', '405', '67', '5035', '21621', 'None', 'NAN', '13', 'None', 'NAN', 'None', 'NAN', 'NAN', 'NAN', '1', 'NAN', 'NAN', 'NAN', 'None', '2245323', '4112646', 'NAN', '35', '26', '90', '80', 'NAN', '162', '20210714121626'

Comment: kindly post your expected output dataframe

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer as per below code . it will provide the out put as desired

```
data = []
records = {}

start = "<record>"
end = "</record>"
########################################

with open('sample.xml') as file :
    for line in file:
        tag,value ="",""
        try:
            temp = re.sub(r"[\n\t\s]*", "", line)
            if temp == start:
                records.clear()

            elif temp == end:
                data.append(records.copy())
                print("end records ", records)
             else:
                line = re.sub(r'[^\w]', ' ', temp) #/\W+/g
                tag = line.split()[0]
                if tag in {"positioning_request_timeutc_off", "positioning_response_timeutc_off", "timeStamputc_off"}:
                    value= line.split()[2]
                else:
                    value = line.split()[1]
                records[tag] = value


        except Exception:
            pass
```